# How can you detect that an arduino is plugged into a computer?

Tags: arduino

Is it possible, on the arduino side, to detect that it's plugged into a computer? I've been looking around but no luck. If so how? and if not why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot detect if a 2009, Uno, etc. is connected since the USB-to-serial chip does not give any indication of such. On the Leonardo, Due, and other boards with USB-capable MCUs you can query the USB registers to see if it is connected to a USB host. You may be able to reprogram the ATmega16U2 on the Uno R3 to tell you, but you may end up losing the ability to program the Uno R3 via USB if done incorrectly.